# Async tasks inside of task

Tags: c#, xml, asynchronous

I'm loading hundreds of xml files to two different datatables in order to bind and display each datatable in a grid. This is for a Windows forms application.

Each query is very different from the other, so running one query and loading both tables doesn't work.

I'm using this to load the xml:

```
    public async Task loadXMLs(List<string> xmlfiles)
    {

        var loadTasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (String xml in xmlfiles)
        {
            loadTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => openXMLs(xml)));
        }            

        await Task.WhenAll(loadTasks);
        
    }
    
    public static async Task openXMLs(string xml)
    {           
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xml);;

        if(xdoc != null)
        {
            loadXMLdatatable1(xdoc, xml);
            loadXMLdatatable2(xdoc, xml);               
        }
    }
    
    public static async Task loadXMLdatatable1(XDocument xdoc, string xml)
    {
        var query = xdoc.Elements (Long query here for XML)
        
        lock(datatable1)
        {
            foreach(var item in query)
            {
                datatable1.Rows.Add(
                    item
                );
            }
        }           
    }
    
    public static async Task loadXMLdatatable2(XDocument xdoc, string xml)
    {
        var query = xdoc.Elements (Long query here for XML)
        
        lock(datatable2)
        {
            foreach(var item in query)
            {
                datatable2.Rows.Add(
                    item
                );
            }
        }           
    }
```

My question is, when I change to this:

```
    public static async Task openXMLs(string xml)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xml); ;

        if (xdoc != null)
        {
            Task dt1 = Task.Run(() => loadXMLdatatable1(xdoc, xml));
            Task dt2 = Task.Run(() => loadXMLdatatable2(xdoc, xml));

            await Task.WhenAll(dt1, dt2);
        }
    }
```

I thought I would see an increase in performance, but the load times are the same.

Am I doing this correctly or is it not possible to run async inside of a task?

Comment: I think you need to attach a profiler or add some other instrumentation to determine where the bottleneck is - I'd be surprised if it was querying an `XDocument` in memory. As an aside, I'd note `XDocument.Load` *cannot* return `null`.

Comment: What is the idea behind putting logic in Tasks and then have the logic be surrounded by locks?

Comment: The `lock` is effectively making the entire process run serially; there is no real parallel processing going on here. The first step is to do some basic profiling by timing each method to find the bottleneck (use the `StopWatch` for a rough estimate). From there, you can start to come up with a revised strategy.

Comment: @CharlesMager Thanks for the info on null, now that I look at it, not sure why I'm doing that.

Comment: @PeterBons The datatables aren't thread safe, so I have to lock them while the records are added. This method has allowed me to load data about 3-4x faster than not using tasks. When I profiled this process originally, quite a bit of the time was spent in Xdocument.Load, so going this way helped a lot. If you have a better method, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with data tables is always awkward, because they just don't support modern concepts of asynchronous loading. So there's a certain point at which you'll just need to switch to a different UI, or make other potentially drastic changes like [virtualized data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-jit-data-loading-in-the-datagrid?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

The best you can do is push as much work as possible outside the lock. In your case, you have a query, but LINQ uses [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-example), so unless you're reifying your query *before* the `lock`, then the actual query is executed inside the lock.

To reify, you can call `ToList` at the end of your query:

```
public static async Task loadXMLdatatable1(XDocument xdoc, string xml)
{
  var items = xdoc.Elements()
      .Whatever(Long query here for XML)
      .ToList();

  lock(datatable1)
  {
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
      datatable1.Rows.Add(item);
    }
  }           
}
```

That way, the query will be executed while not holding the lock.

If that doesn't provide sufficient performance improvement, or if your query *already* ends with reification, then you'll just need to use data virtualization (possibly with a UI rewrite).

Comment: Thanks, the ToList() does make a big difference. I didn't know about the reify and lock, very helpful.